# Curl результат ошибка 3

Tags: curl

Здраствуйте. Разбираюв с помощью курл в цикле масив урлов:

```
 function curl($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        if(output  === false)
        {
            echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch) .  'Код curl: ' . curl_errno($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }

    foreach ($urls as url){
   $result =  curl($url);
    }
```

Но при выводе результата в некоторых случаях все проходит хорошо, но в большинстве возвращает `Ошибка curl: malformed Код curl: 3`,хотя ссылки рабочие и в браузере отображаются коректно. Ставил `sleep()` чтобы замедлить выполнение скрипта - не помогает. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: что-то я тут внутри цикла вижу определение функции, а не ее вызов. Вы с какой целью таким образом код нам даете, который в принципе работать не может? и почему у вас 2 раза `curl_exec` происходит?

Comment: Добавил просто для демонстации, и так понятно как она работает. Но если нет могу переделать,если в этом вся проблема для вас

Comment: вот теперь еще дополните примером URL на которые ругается. При этом если в запросе происходит редирект, то напишите всю цепочку URL.

Comment: http://olx.ua/uk/ajax/misc/contact/phone/n8yVC/%20HTTP/1.1/

Comment: у вас с отдельной взятой этой URL тоже не работает? т.к. у меня работает. зы: `output` вместо `$output` в `if`е месте написано

Comment: с отдельно взятой работает, в цикле нет. Синтаксическая ошибка ни к чему,наспех скопировал просто

Comment: я вам про корректность кода говорю, к тому, чтобы когда другие пользователю сюда зашли не тратили бы свое время на поиск опечаток и прочей ваших ленивых ошибок. Уважайте тех кто вам будет отвечать. задавайте вопрос нормально, а не тяп-ляп.

Comment: Я уже не первый раз сюда захожу, и все ноормально, но почему то иногда появляются существа которые думают что они лучше других и могут всех вокруг учить жизни. Я уважаю всех кто хочет искренне помочь, а не рисовать из себя Бога. Поэтому если вам нечего сказать по моей проблеме,то спасибо и на этом, учите других быть сятыми.

Comment: рекомендую перестать хамить и прочитать раздел справки [mcve], особенно в части про _воспроизводимость_. Если вы не в состоянии нормально описать проблему, не надо на меня из-за этого злиться.